# Adding timestamp to ffmpeg output raw images

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://host:port -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgba -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 pipe:1
```

I am using ffmpeg to pull a RTSP stream and output raw frames(images) to pipe as above. And my application successfully consumes the images from its stdout pipe.

Here my application also needs the timestamp of each frame so that it can overlap the image back to original stream after processing the image. How should I do that for a raw image stream?  Change to AVI format?